# how to search for a string match within a set of key values

Tags: ruby

I need a simple way to search through a string to match another string.

```
example:
domain.com
```

data that looks like this:

```
test[0][:element] = "foo.com domain.com bar.com"
```

The domains are separated by a space.
`test[]` is an array of hashes.

I was thinking something along these lines of:

```
test[0][:element].select #?
```

Comment: What should be the result of your search? Where do you want to search, only for the `:element` key or the entire hash, array. Please update your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'foo.com domain.com bar.com'.split.include?('domain.com') # => true
```

Now if I understand you correctly, you want to find all hashes which have a value, which contains that domain:

```
test.select { |hash| hash.values.any? { |value| value.split.include?('domain.com') } }
```

Comment: Your code will also return `true` for `com bar.com`.

Comment: @Jordan, didn't follow. Can you write the specific example you are trying to express?

Comment: Here's a better example: `'foo.com domain.com bar.com'.include?('main.com')` will also return `true`, which is almost certainly not what OP wants.